Publishing Angular with .NET Core to a remote site
Does anyone have any experience with this?
I built the program using VS 2022. I set the startup project as the .Server project, where the API lives, and have the Angular 18 program in a .Client project. The entire thing works in development.
In the .csproj for the server project, I believe it instantiates the client correctly:
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <SpaRoot>..\calorieassistant.client</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:4200</SpaProxyServerUrl>
</PropertyGroup>

I post it to the remote site using VS and the site's deployment document, which works without errors.
No luck - I get the 'fail to load' when I go to the site (it WAS running the 'this site is just hosted' blurb before).
Has anyone done this or do you see something I did wrong?
The site is https://calorieassistant.com if you want to check it

Hi TheWizardOfTN, I am familiar with deployment issue, could you find the publish files in your cloud platform, we need to check it. By the way, here is the detailed steps how to deploy the spa project.

It turned out that the answer for this was simple
I had set up a .server project for the API and a .client project for the Angular project in VS2022. When I tried to build it, Studio pushed all of the Angular build files to a subdirectory under the .client called 'dist.'
I added a wwwroot folder under the .server project manually, built the project and published it, and it worked perfectly well.
That's it - I'm publishing this here so that someone else who's new to Angular does waste a day on so easy a fix
